# Are there any publicly available spell checking corpora?

Tags: computational-linguistics, orthography, corpora, lexicon, resource-request

I need some corpora that contain **sentences with misspelled word(s)** in order to evaluate the performance of my own spell checking approach. So, the corpora should define **the right word alongside the misspelled one.**

Comment: Here is a misspell checker for English http://www.webspellchecker.net/web-services.html | You can use its own API to request in JSON or XML format. However, it is paid.